# Why a specific Image size takes more execution time in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph

I am testing execution time for low pass Butterworth image processing filter in MATLAB. While running my code for different image sizes starting from 64x64 with an increment of 64 in each dimension, I found that a particular image dimension 1984x1984 takes noticeably more time than the other dimensions like 1920x1920 and 2048x2048 size images and onwards. The following graph shows the plot of average execution time (for 10 iterations) against the image dimensions.

[image]

Any reasoning for this seemingly abnormal behavior of the graph? Following is my code. Thanks.

```
f=imread('1984x1984_2.pgm');
[M,N]=size(f);
tic
%FFT of the image after padding values of the same size as image
F=single(fft2(f,2*M,2*N));
%FFT shift
Fc=single(fftshift(F));
%deleting large matrix to release memory
delete F 
%initializing the filter of the same size as the padded image
H=single(zeros(2*M,2*N));
%calculating filter values
for u=1:2*M;
for v=1:2*N;
radius = ((u-(M+1))^2 + (v-(N+1))^2)^.5; 
H(u,v)= 1./(1.0 +  (radius./ 40).^(2*2));
end;
end;
filter=H;
%multiply the filter with image spectrum
G=H.*Fc;
%deleting large matrix to release memory
delete Fc
%Inverse FFT shift
Gsh=single(ifftshift(G));
%deleting large matrix to release memory
delete G H 
%Inverse FFT to transform the image in spatial domain
Ginv=ifft2(Gsh,2*M,2*N);
%deleting large matrix to release memory
delete Gsh
%converting to real and unpadding
Greal=single(real(Ginv(1:M,1:N)));
resultImage=Greal;
t=toc*1000
```

Comment: Hard to say if we don't even know what your code is doing...a good start point could be to split your code in smaller parts and to test which one of them has this "strange" behavior...

Comment: Try to use the run+timer (profiler) function to see which lines take to much time and try to find out why they do it in your special case of the dimension 1984x1984.

Comment: Post some code. I think this is potentially and interesting question.